# Blender Runs Unusably Slow and Buggy on Windows 10 with GTX 1080

Tags: windows

I am new to Blender and 3D modeling in general. After downloading the newest version of Blender, I found the UI to be incredibly unresponsive and laggy. I looked up solutions online, such as changing the way the window is rendered or adding Blender.exe to the Nvidia 3D control panel and using all of the settings available. The only thing I could not do is run Blender with integrated graphics since I have no integrated graphics card in my desktop, so the option does not appear.

I have:
GTX 1080
Intel i7-4790K CPU 4.00GHz
16 GB RAM
Windows 10
2 500GB SSDs

I even checked a post on [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/blender-lag-everywhere-when-interacting-with-ui-win10-gtx-1070) with a similar problem and computer specs, but none of the solutions worked, some even made things worse. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. Check your Task Manager, see if you have any CPU-hungry operations going in in the background. I found that removing GeForce Experience also increased performance. The fact that you have no Integrated graphics card might be a problem: unlikely, but do report this issue with the folks at Blender directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response OroNZ. I checked to see what my CPU usage was while running Blender, and it doesn't even go above 30%. It seems to cap out at 6 GB Memory usage though, despite having 16 GB total